# Read input.txt file and also output.bmp file from terminal (C-programming)

Tags: c, terminal, console, stdin, fopen

I have to do an assignment where I have to write a C-Programm, where it gets the input-file-name from the console as command line parameter.
It should move the data from the input.txt file (the input file has the information for the bmp file - color etc.) to the generated output.png file. The 20 20 parameters stand for width and height for the output.png image.

So the console-request for example (tested on Linux) will look like this:

```
./main input.txt output.bmp 20 20
```

I know that this code reads an input.txt File and puts it on the screen.

```
FILE *input;
int ch;
input = fopen("input.txt","r");
ch = fgetc(input);
while(!feof(input)) {
    putchar(ch);
    ch = fgetc(input);
}
fclose(input);
```

And this would (for example) write it to the output.png file.

```
FILE *output;
int i;
     output = fopen("ass2_everyinformationin.bmp", "wb+"); 
 for( i = 0; i < 55; i++)               
 {
     fputc(rectangle_bmp[i], output);
 }
 fclose(output);
```

But this code works only, if I hard-code the name directly in the code, not by using a command line parameters.
I don't have any clue, how to implement that and I also didn't find any helpful information in the internet, maybe someone can help me.

Greetings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Are you aware of the parameters to main()? I.e. argc and argv.

Comment: @Yunnosch no i am not.. do I need them get the wanted result?

Comment: Without using them it will be hard, with using them easy. One tells you how many arguments your program got, the other represents an array providing them as "strings". Find a tutorial which does not start with `int main()` or `int main(void)`.

Comment: thanks a lot for that tipp! Do you know a good (and easy) turorial by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full prototype for a standard main() is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

You get an int with the number of arguments, `argc` and
a list of "strings" (as far as they exist in C), `argv`.

You can for example use

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    printf("Number: %d\n", argc);
    printf("0: %s\n", argv[0]);
    if (1<argc)
    {
        printf("1: %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

to start playing with the arguments.

Note that this is intentionally not implementing anything but a basic example of using command line parameters. This matches an accpeted StackOverflow policy of providing help with assignments, without going anywhere near solving them.