# Incorporating STDIN

Tags: c

I completed the following code that adds two roman numerals together. I just need to incorporate STDIN, so that the user can type in `./a.out "<input.txt>"` to use an input file containing the Roman numerals to be added. It requires two inputs only, with the inputs in a simple text file. It should never prompt the user. The code is completed below, just without the above, it requires two inputs, with the inputs being in a simple text file.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>    
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void predigit(char num1, char num2);

void postdigit(char c, int n);

char romanval[1000];

int p=0;

int main()

{

   char rom1[30], rom2[30];

   int a[30], l1, l2, i, k1, k2, dec,j;

   long k;

   printf("Enter the two roman numbers\n");

   scanf("%s%s", &rom1,&rom2);

   l1 =strlen(rom1);

   for(i = 0; i < l1; i++)

   {

      switch (rom1[i])

      {

     case 'I': a[i] = 1;

            break;

     case 'V': a[i] = 5;

            break;

     case 'X': a[i] = 10;

            break;

     case 'L': a[i] = 50;

            break;

     case 'C': a[i] = 100;

            break;

     case 'D': dec = dec + 500;

            break;

     case 'M': a[i] = 1000;

            break;

     default : printf("Invalid choice");

            break;

      }

   }

   k1 = a[l1 - 1];

   for(i = l1 - 1; i > 0; i--)

   {

      if(a[i] > a[i - 1])

      {

     k1 = k1 - a[i - 1];

      }

      if(a[i] <= a[i - 1])

      {

     k1 = k1 + a[i - 1];

      }

   }

    l2 =strlen(rom2);

   for(i = 0; i < l2; i++)

   {

      switch (rom2[i])

      {

     case 'I': a[i] = 1;

            break;

     case 'V': a[i] = 5;

            break;

     case 'X': a[i] = 10;

            break;

     case 'L': a[i] = 50;

            break;

     case 'C': a[i] = 100;

            break;

     case 'D': dec = dec + 500;

            break;

     case 'M': a[i] = 1000;

            break;

     default : printf("Invalid choice");

            break;

      }

   }

   k2 = a[l2 - 1];

   for(i = l2 - 1; i > 0; i--)

   {

      if(a[i] > a[i - 1])

      {

     k2 = k2 - a[i - 1];

      }

      if(a[i] <= a[i - 1])

      {

     k2 = k2 + a[i - 1];

      }

   }

   k= k1+k2;

   printf("decimal equivalent is %d", k);

        if (k <= 0)

        {

          printf("Invalid number");

          return 0;

        }

       while (k != 0)

         {

          if (k >= 1000)

            {

                postdigit('M', k / 1000);

                k = k - (k / 1000) * 1000;

            }

            else if (k >= 500)

            {

                if (k < (500 + 4 * 100))

                {

                    postdigit('D', k / 500);

                    k = k - (k / 500) * 500;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('C','M');

                    k = k - (1000-100);

                }

            }

            else if (k >= 100)

            {

                if (k < (100 + 3 * 100))

                {

                    postdigit('C', k / 100);

                    k = k - (k / 100) * 100;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('L', 'D');

                    k = k - (500 - 100);

                }

            }

            else if (k >= 50 )

            {

                if (k < (50 + 4 * 10))

                {

                    postdigit('L', k / 50);

                    k = k - (k / 50) * 50;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('X','C');

                    k = k - (100-10);

                }

            }

            else if (k >= 10)

            {

                if (k < (10 + 3 * 10))

                {

                    postdigit('X', k / 10);

                    k = k - (k / 10) * 10;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('X','L');

                    k = k - (50 - 10);

                }

            }

            else if (k >= 5)

            {

                if (k < (5 + 4 * 1))

                {

                    postdigit('V', k / 5);

                    k = k - (k / 5) * 5;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('I', 'X');

                    k = k - (10 - 1);

                }

            }

            else if (k >= 1)

            {

                if (k < 4)

                {

                    postdigit('I', k / 1);

                    k = k - (k / 1) * 1;

                }

                else

                {

                    predigit('I', 'V');

                    k = k - (5 - 1);

                }

            }

        }

        printf("\nRoman number is: ");

        for(j = 0; j < p; j++)

            printf("%c", romanval[j]);

        return 0;

    }

    void predigit(char num1, char num2)

    {

        romanval[p++] = num1;

        romanval[p++] = num2;

    }

    void postdigit(char c, int n)

    {

        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)

            romanval[p++] = c;

    }
```

Comment: you want to read `rom1` and `rom2` from the file ?

Comment: it actually supports stdin already, you should just try it first... Although your `scanf` should have a space between `%s` and `%s` ... ALSO your input.txt has to be well formed, but it will work

Comment: @achal yes I do

Comment: and @AhmedMasud thank you!

Comment: @AhmedMasud I don't think that's what she means. From her `./a.out "<input.txt>` example, I'm thinking she meant how to pass the text file in as a command line parameter

Comment: I thought it shouldn't ask the user for input

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez Thats correct!!

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: Assuming that getting at the file name is sufficient and opening/reading it can be solved by OP: Possible duplicate of [Read input.txt file and also output.bmp file from terminal (C-programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535120/read-input-txt-file-and-also-output-bmp-file-from-terminal-c-programming)

Comment: @muneeb_ahmed Please explain why you think that `./a.out "<input.txt>"` is closer to OPs intention.

Comment: You've got the question backwards. `scanf` reads from `stdin`. What you want to do is allow the program to take a file name on its command line so it can open that file and read from something *other than* `stdin`.