# Checking command line argument for valid digit

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that requires the user to enter a VALID integer as a command argument. I have tried literally everything I can think of and I can't get it to work. I have went through probably 10 different functions, scraping each one because I can tweak it to work.

This is what I have at the moment..

```
int checkdigit(char *argv) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(argv); i++) {
        if (argv[i] >= 48 && argv[i] <= 57) {
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("Not valid");
            return 1;
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

This prints "Not valid" no matter what I give it.

Comment: You’re skipping every character after each valid digit.

Comment: There are two  `i++` remove one.

Comment: Juding from the name of your parameter, you might have misunderstood the entire concept of using command line parameters. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536091/7733418

Comment: Don't use "magic numbers" like 48 and 57, that makes the code harder to read. Use the proper character constants instead: `if(argv[i] >= '0' && argv[i] <= '9')`.  And if the condition in the for loop is `<= strlen(argv)`, then you are going to read the `'\0'`-terminating bytes. The correct condition should be `< strlen(argv)`.#

Answer (score 1):

your condition is wrong while iterating in `argv`. It should be  `i<strlen(argv)` instead of `i<=strlen(argv)`. Also there are two `i++` which will skip every valid digits.

here is the working one

```
int checkdigit(char *argv) {
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<strlen(argv); i++) {
                if (argv[i] >= 48 && argv[i] <= 57) {
                        continue;
                } else {
                        printf("Not valid");
                        return 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Also make sure you are calling `checkdigit()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing an integer through `argv`, why wouldn't you use `atoi`? All you have to do is validate your parameters to verify you actually did pass enough arguments in.

The `atoi` function takes in a `const char*` argument and returns an `int`, which sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            printf("Digit: %d\n", atoi(argv[i]));
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Input:

```
./a.out 1 a 4 hello 72
```

Output:

```
Digit: 1
Digit: 0
Digit: 4
Digit: 0
Digit: 72
```

---

Update: Upon further research, `strtol` is the function you need. `atoi` [does no error checking](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), and the C standard says nothing regarding what happens when `atoi` returns an error, so the function isn't considered safe, so while I initially thought the function was returning zero, it was actually returning an error.

If you have access to `strtonum`, that function is very reliable from  what I've seen. I don't have access to it myself, since it seems to only be available on FreeBSD.

If you don't have access to that though, `strtol` is the way to go. It takes a `const char*` as input, so it does accept the right input for what you're looking for, as well as an end pointer and a base, and in addition [it legitimately returns 0](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) on both successes and failure. It's at least [going to be safer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf2/strtol.htm) than using `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `#include <ctype.h>` at the top, I'd write your function this way:

```
  int checkdigit(char *argv) {
     int i = 0;
     for(i = 0; i<strlen(argv); i++) {
        if( !isdigit(argv[i]) ) {
           printf("Not valid");
           return 1;
        }
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

This would have the advantage of portability to non ASCII-based codepage environments, like IBM's System 39 or OS/400 which are EBCDIC based (in most native cases), and characters '0'-'9' have values 0xF0 through 0xF9.