# Why is no argument passed in main function?

Tags: c++, c

Whenever we define main() function in any code, why don't we pass any argument in it?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c.

Comment: Show some code you have tried. Add minimal, complete, and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8):

The C++ standard sanctioned variations of [`main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) are:

```
int main () { body }
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }
```

The C standard sanctioned variations of [`main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) are:

```
int main (void) { body }
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }
```

There are other platform-specific variations, but all of them must return an `int`.

It appears that you have only seen programs that use the first version of `main()`. Most real-world applications use the second version of `main()`. It allows them to process command-line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You only pass arguments when calling a function, but that might just be a difference in terminology between the two of us.
While defining a function we define the formal parameters, including their types.
If you have never seen a `main()` defined with parameters, then you have never seen a `main()` which can handle commandline parameters.

The usual prototype for a `main()` which can handle them is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

For an example of how to use this, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536091/7733418

Answer (score 0):

The main syntax is

`int main(int argc, char **argv);`

In which, `argc` refers to the number of command line arguments passed in, which includes the actual name of the program, as invoked by the user. `argv` contains the actual arguments, starting with index `1`. Index `0` is the program name.

Comment: "*which includes the actual name of the program*" - **usually**, but not always true in some edge cases. So `argv[0]` is the program name only when the name is actually present.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not always same? Can you tell us some examples?