# Echo string to a c program in powershell

Tags: c, powershell, parameter-passing

I see this in a code challenge before and was wondering if this was the same as passing a parameter to a program?

> Echo “string”| program.c

---

Comment: No. It is not the same. It passes it to standard input of the program.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Would be an unusually named executable, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, `@AnttiHaapala` would be an unusual name for an executable, and so would `program.c`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Chapeau. Nice intentional misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown code will probably not work at all, because `program.c`, if named according to the habits of practically any programmer, will be the pure C-code file, the "human readable" form of a program.
To use this in any way as an executable, you first need to build it (compile and link). The result it usually an executable file called `program` (or `program.exe` on Windows).
That file can be called similarly to the shown code

```
echo "string" | program
```

Which makes the string available via the diverse input functions ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io ) and the standard input.

For accessing it as a parameter (using the parameters to `main`, function, usually named `argc` and `argv`; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536091/7733418 ), you'd have to call the program like

```
program "string"
```