# Get the name of an input file passed in by redirection?

Tags: c++, bash, io-redirection

Lets say I get something like this in Linux / Bash:

```
./my_program <input_file.in
```

is there a way in my code to check the name of my input file?

something like this?

```
if (strcmp(in,"desired_input_file_name.in")) {
   printf("success!!"\n);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? How to read input like this? Or how to use `strcmp` properly?

Comment: I don't think you can do that if you stream the file contents to stdin via bash. However you can pass the filename as a parameter to your program for comparing, you then have to open the file yourself if you want the contents.

Comment: You could change to filename as parameter to your program instead of input redirection (which I think makes impossible what you want to do). Would that be an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read input.txt file and also output.bmp file from terminal (C-programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535120/read-input-txt-file-and-also-output-bmp-file-from-terminal-c-programming)

Comment: If you accept input from `stdin`, as would be the case of input from the shell, you do not have control of the input, which may or may not even be a file (e.g., `echo Hi | ./my_program`). If you must know the input file, then require it as a param and don't use `stdin`. If knowing the file allows for certain optimizations or features, you could support both an input file and `stdin` and default to reading `stdin` (and not using those optimizations/features) only when there is no input file given as an argument.

Answer (score 10):

There is no portable simple way. Piping via `<` will redirect the contents of `input_file.in` to the standard input of `my_program`. Its the same as if you had typed the contents of the file. If you want to know the filename then you need to pass that, eg as command line argument:

```
./my_program input_file.in
```

Comment: To be pedantic, there is a way, it's just a bad idea. You can jump through hoops to get the file name, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

There's a non-portable solution. Linux has proc filesystem which can be used to get the info. You can get the file descriptor of `stdin` and then get the filename from it - using [`fileno(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) and [`readlink(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) calls.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[512], file[512] = {0};

    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fileno(stdin));
    readlink(buf, file, sizeof file - 1);

    printf("File name: %s\n", file);
}
```

(error checks omitted for brevity)

Comment: You also need to check if the file descriptor refers to a regular file with `fstat()`.  It could be a pipe, a tty, or even a socket.

Comment: Indeed. If the input could be different (than the file direction) then `fstat(2)` would help differentiate.