# String from command line argument in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, variable-assignment, incompatibletypeerror

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char file1 = argv[1];
    char file2 = argv[2];
}
```

I am getting an error message here - initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast. file1 and file2 are the names of files. How can I approach to this?

Comment: `char` -> `char *`

Comment: The variable `argv` is an array of *pointers* to `char`. Each element is of the type`char *`.

Comment: Oh, and never use the pointers in the `argv` array unless you have checked `argc` first, to make sure that the indexes are valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read input.txt file and also output.bmp file from terminal (C-programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535120/read-input-txt-file-and-also-output-bmp-file-from-terminal-c-programming)

Comment: Note that the Q/A I proposed as duplicate is using the format specifier for "strings" i.e. **pointer to char** in C world. That is how I think it answers this question about why using a `char` does not work. (Yes it is one of my answers. I will happily confirm and "comment-tick" any OTHER proposed good or better duplicate.)

Comment: There is one single exception to @Someprogrammerdude's rule: The `argv`-array is null-terminated, too (guaranteed by the standard), so instead of checking `argc`, you could alternatively relay on that as well, like `for(char**p = argv; *p; ++p) { /* use *p */ }`. That's rarely used, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` and `argv[2]` have the type `char *` that point to strings while objects `file1` and `file2` have the type char and are not pointers. So the compiler issues an error that you are trying to assign pointers (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`) to characters (`file1` and `file2`) that does not make a sense..

```
char file1 = argv[1];
char file2 = argv[2];
```

You need to write

```
char *file1 = argv[1];
char *file2 = argv[2];
```

In this case the pointers `file1` and `file2` will point to the user supplied strings that denote file names.